# Ruby on Rails Redmine Active Record::Record not found for select pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redmine

I've recently started at a new company which uses Redmine and I've been asked to upgrade from 2.3.3 to 3.0.3 - complete novice with Ruby and Rails but it seems OK so far.

I've installed an instance of 3.0.3 and updated the database using mysqldump.  It seems to have largely worked, however random wiki pages on the new Redmine don't work - simply get a 404 error in the browser.

Everything else has succeeded - all user credentials, config for the application, many projects, issues etc, and in fact many wikis - just not some of them.  I have been unable to interpret what I am getting from the error logs.

My environment details are:

- CentOS 6.5 / Red Hat 4.4.7-11 (tried on both, result is the same)
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 4.2.1
- Redmine 3.0.3

The output from the production log for the app is below -

```
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all Versions with 'id': (all, {:include=>:attachments}) [WHERE `versions`.`project_id` = ?] (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)):
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in render_on'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:117:in `map'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:117:in `block in render_on'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `each'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `block in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `tap'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:167:in `call_hook'
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1229:in `view_layouts_base_sidebar_hook_response'
  app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:53:in `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb__2179447321350669763_44059640'
  app/controllers/wiki_controller.rb:97:in `show'
```

And I haven't been able to find anything relating to similar issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been dragging on for a long time and this is the last step before we can roll this upgrade out.

Thanks.

Comment: Not familiar with Redmine I'm afraid. Did you use the instructions here (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade) to do the upgrade?

Comment: A combination of those instructions and these ones (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) as I have tried both upgrading existing 2.3.3 instances and installing fresh 3.0.3 instances).  Same issue regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was an incompatible plugin.  The Download button plugin was causing this issue and once it was removed and "bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" run again, the problem was resolved.